# Find a named link on the page, then go click it - in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using Greasekit, so needs this to be in Javascript, please

## What I would tell a human to do

Click the link called `< Previous` so that it opens in a new window 
(in the example below, it goes to Page 22, but it could be any number, so it really needs to look **for this specific** link)

```
<table class="v_page_nav" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">Showing 551-575 of 610 Results</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=22" id="pagination-prev-link">
                < Previous</a>| Page:</td>
        <td class="off">
<a href="/gp/vine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=1" id="pagination-page-1">1</a>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="off">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=22" id="pagination-page-22">22</a>
        </td>
        <td class="on">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=23" id="pagination-page-23">23</a>
        </td>
        <td class="off">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=24" id="pagination-page-24">24</a>
        </td>
        <td class="off">
<a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=25" id="pagination-page-25">25</a>
        </td>
        <td>| <a href="/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&amp;page=24" id="pagination-next-link">Next ></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## The code:

the last two lines of the answer are probably:

```
link.target="_blank";
link.click();
```

(this is to open the link in the new window)
..but what I want to know is how to write the rest of the code; the lines that go above it.

## Note

an alternative to finding `< Previous` might be to look for a link with the id `pagination-prev-link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your last sentence:

```
var link = document.getElementById('pagination-prev-link');
```

Comment: **Excellent, thanks!!** What would happen on a page where this link wasn't active (for example, page 1 where there is no previous page to click on) --- just tried it, the answer is : nothing

Comment: In that case, `link` will be undefined, so don't try to call any method on it, or access its properties (i.e., don't do `link.something`).